# JavaFX: own TextField with a maximum of 2 characters ... can not replace all marked characters

Tags: javafx, textfield

When typing in MyTextFieldMaxLength2:
a)  '1' mark and click on number 9 => will be replaced = '9' ... ok
b) '12' mark and click on number 9 => nothing happens

How can I get that even if all two numbers are marked, this is replaced by a new number?

```
public class MyTextFieldMaxLength2 extends TextField {

    public boolean ifCondition_validate(String text) {
        return (getText().length() < 2 || text.equals("")) && text.matches("[0-9]*");
    }


    @Override
    public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
        if ( ifCondition_validate(text) ) {
            super.replaceText(start, end, text);
        }       
    }   

    @Override
    public void replaceSelection(String text) {
        if ( ifCondition_validate(text) ) {
            super.replaceSelection(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by setting a `TextFormatter` on a standard text field, instead of subclassing text field:

```
TextField textField = new TextField();

UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = c -> {
    String proposedText = c.getControlNewText();
    if (proposedText.matches("[0-9]{0,2}")) {
        return c ;
    } else {
        return null ;
    }
};
textField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<String>(filter));
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the solution. I am working on a large graphical application, using the SceneBuilder. I like the concept of own TextField classes with special properties to build and then uniformly over
to use SceneBuilder. I was hoping that there was a solution to the problem directly within the MyTextFieldMaxLength2-class
, so that the functionality can be bundled cleanly within the derived TextField classes.


I'll wait a few more days maybe someone has an idea. In the other case, I take your solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sten why don't you just use this solution in a text field subclass?

Comment: I've discarded my idea using the TextField subclass. I stay with your direct approach and have only the filter method as static rebuilt. 
So I have to use the filter methods, e.g. "filter_onlyMax2Numbers", "filter_only0xOr1xComma" only once and can then use them anywhere in the application. This is how it works very well. Thank you.